# Why can't I access the object property in a foreach PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm looping through some data which looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [email] => email@email.com
        [fname] => joe1
        [lname] => someone
        [sent] => 0
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [email] => email1@email.com
        [fname] => joe2
        [lname] => someone
        [sent] => 0
    )

)
```

I'm simply looping through the array like this...

```
foreach ($recipients as $key => $u) {
    //build email
    echo $u->fname;

            }
```

Nothing is echoed and I receive this error

Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Thanks for any help.

Comment: and what happens then? looks good from here. How come you dont' actually describe what happens? Didn't it occur to you to provide as much information as possible, to get better help instead of snarky comments like these? :)

Comment: What error are you getting?  And can we have a look at the code wherein $recipients is defined/populated?

Comment: @Nanne this site wouldn't be awesome if it wasn't for snarky comments :-) Apologies, added the actual error

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of that `$u` (assuming it's that echo line) and look at what it is. Also, do a `var_dump` of that recipients. Debug what you see.

Comment: @MrVimes It was my error, when I looked at how recipients was populated, I stupidly did this $recipients[] = Sorry to waste anyones time

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem is that `$u` is not always a `stdClass` you expect. I would just change the code this way to see what happens:

```
foreach ($recipients as $key => $u) {

    if (!is_object($u)) {
         echo "\$u is not an object!";
         var_dump($u);
         exit;
    }

    if (!property_exists($u, 'fname')) {
         echo "property fname is not defined!";
         var_dump($u);
    }

    echo $u->fname;
}
```